# Why doesn't my observable terminate at error?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, reactivex

```
Observable.interval(1000)
  .flatMap(() => this.http.get('abc'))
  .subscribe(
      // x => console.log('Next: ' + x) // Don't terminite without this.
  );
```

This http request gives an error due to 404. But the stream keeps polling.

However, as soon as I uncomment the commented line in `subscribe`, it terminates on the first error.

See example here

http://plnkr.co/edit/bQyBvboFJCPyZUEFjraX?p=preview

Why is that?

#### Update

Seems a bug, reported [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1921#issuecomment-246131406)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I'm correct but by checking the source I think it happens like this:

1. Calling `.subscribe()` without any argument leads to a [call to `toSubscribe()` in Observable.ts#L90](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observable.ts#L90).
2. This call returns an empty instance of `Subscriber` class [in toSubscriber.ts#L21 `return new Subscriber()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/util/toSubscriber.ts#L21)
3. Calling [Subscribe() without any parameters](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts#L62) creates an [`empty` Observer](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observer.ts) which does literally nothing.
4. I think this is where the problem happens. When you subscribe to the Observable resulting from `flatMap` (btw, it's been [renamed to `mergeMap`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#operators-renamed-or-removed)) it's supposed to unsubscribe from the Observable [on error in mergeMap.ts#L12](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/mergeMap.ts#L120) but this never happens because the [`empty` Observer does nothing on Observer.ts#L34](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observer.ts#L34).

So the Observable keeps emitting values because the Observer never unsubscribes. I'm not sure this is what really happens but if it does I don't know whether it's a bug or a feature.